# How to get the response data from promise in React?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am setting up a very basic react app, and trying to call my local host server (separate backend server), which has JSON data on it. I want to extract the data returned from the promise, but nothing I do seems to work. Here is my code:

```
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/posts')
    .then(function(response) {
        const items = response.json()
        console.log(items)
    })
```

I have tried response.json(), response.body, I tried logging the body with .then(functio(body) { console.log(body)}), response.data, response.body, but nothing works. Here is what the console prints out:

[image]

How can I take the output it is giving me, and get it in an array that I can iterate through? The "content" and "id" are what I need access to.

and FYI, the array, when i go to localhost:8080/posts in my browser is simple:

```
  [{"id":1,"content":"hello, this is post 1"}]
```

any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: what's code of your console print out

Comment: the code that I put, const items = response.json()
        console.log(items), yields the print out that I put in the image.

Comment: response.data prints "undefined"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The call to`response.json()`will also return a promise so you need too handle that also. Try the code below.

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/posts')
.then(function(response){ return response.json(); })
.then(function(data) {
    const items = data;
    console.log(items)
})
```

Comment: So, why I can find this code snippet also executable if the response.json() already returns a promise :

    fetch('api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts')
            .then(response => response.json() as Promise<WeatherForecast[]>)
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({ forecasts: data, loading: false });
            });

Comment: how to access the const items in this code outside? Any other way than using setState?

Comment: I think you can access it in the (no var declaration) global scope, but the question you should ask is how can I be sure it is set except when "then" callback is called.